# How to avoid ignored tests being generated as in SpecFlow MsTest?

Tags: specflow

Here is the Sample feature file, has @ignore examples.

```
@ChildTest
Scenario: Sub Report

Given  I have clicked on EmpId: '<EmpId>' to view Report
When   Loading mask is hidden
Then   I have clicked on 'Back to Results' link.

@ignore
Examples:
    | EmpId              | Date    |     
    | CHILD_TEST_SKIPPED | dynamic |
```

I would like TestGenerator to **AVOID Unit test method generation** for @ignore examples

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the test generator to ignore those tests. SpecFlow tags become `[Test category("ignore")]` attributes above the test methods that get generated.

You will need to filter out those tests in Test Explorer. Enter `-trait:ignore` in the Test Explorer search bar to exclude those tests.

An alternative is to set the test to "pending":

```
Scenario: ...
    Given pending
```

And in the step definition for `Given pending` call: `Assert.Inconclusive("This test is temporarily disabled.");`

Then the tests get executed, but report that they are neither passing nor failing. I do this quite a bit when implementing new features so I can write the tests ahead of time.